# Is it possible to view VsCode extensions history?

Tags: visual-studio-code, expo

Is it possible to see which extensions I have recently removed in VsCode?

I removed a whole bunch of extensions today, and discovered that I removed one which I need for expo to run, but I do not know which one it is.

Comment: do you get a complaint that it can't execute a command, the command name is a hint of the needed extension

Answer (score 0):

`<current-user-home-folder>\.vscode\extensions\.obsolete`

For Windows would be something like:
`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.vscode\extensions\.obsolete`

while for Linux or MacOS should be in:
`cat ~/.vscode/extensions/.obsolete`